# How to get EF to use an entity as a parameter for an import stored procedure?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities

Imagine I have a stored procedure like so:

```
create proc Foo 
@num1 int,
@num2 int,
@num3 int
as
select @num1+@num2 +@num3
```

If I import the stored procedure into EF and I get a method with 3 parameters, I can map the result to an entity, but how do I get EF to take an entity as parameter, so that I have a method with just 1 parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static SomeType DoTheFoo(this DbContext context,Foo foo)
    {
       return context.ImportedSproc(foo.num1, foo.num2, foo.num3);
    }
}
```